# String manipulation functions like slice substring and substr removed spaces from a string

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to insert a word to a string. For this I'm using `slice` function but it removes my spaces. I also tried this with `substring` and `substr`. I also looked a the code and it uses array manipulations and I believe this is the problem. What can I do?

Example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nhxse7g/3/).

**JavaScript**

```
var string = "spaces are to come                                     ";
var fruits = string.slice(0,25);
    fruits = fruits + 'suzi';

fruits.toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
```

Comment: Try replacing the spaces with `&nbsp;` which is the html entity code for a nonbreaking space. You might have to change the slice length though.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: I'm assuming he want to have multiple spaces between the word come and the word suzi when he adds the string to the innerHTML.

Answer (score 2):

Try it out in the console the script doesn't remove the white spaces. If you want to see all white spaces in an html page you should check the CCS white-space property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

The default for all browsers is to collapse multiple white spaces into a single one.

Comment: hi 10x for the help but unfortunately this didn't work. see example https://jsfiddle.net/1nhxse7g/5/

Comment: Go back to the link in my answer, scroll down, read the **Property Values** paragraph. Of course it doesn't work with "nowrap", you have to use "pre" or "pre-wrap". https://jsfiddle.net/6Ltmmwfq/

Answer (score 0):

try to inspect the output - your spaces are still there, but your browser does not render it.
if you want to make sure that the spaces are displayed you could convert them into " "